# How to monitor that the filesystem pathname is renamed in C or inotify?

Tags: c, linux, inotify

In this code, I am monitoring a file and a directory. But I have a problem that I want to solve and that is, what condition to put that which file or a directory is renamed? Although the `IN_MODIFY` only works with the file when that file text is modified. But I want to monitor that **if the file or directory is renamed**

Is it possible with `inotify` or with `C`?

```
int main(){
  int length, i = 0, fd, wd;
  char buffer[EVENT_BUF_LEN];

  fd = inotify_init();
  if (fd < 0){
      perror( "inotify_init" );
  }
  wd = inotify_add_watch(fd, pathname1, IN_MODIFY);
  length = read( fd, buffer, EVENT_BUF_LEN); 
  if(length < 0){
      perror("read");
  }  

  while(i < length){     
    struct inotify_event *event = ( struct inotify_event *)&buffer[i];
      if(event->len){
          if(event->mask & IN_MODIFY){
              if(event->mask & IN_ISDIR){
                if(event->wd == wd){
                  // if directory name changed. I don't know what condition to put
                  printf("The directory name '%s' is changed with %s\n", event->name);
                }
              }
              else{
                if(event->wd == wd){
                  // if file name changed. I don't know what condition to put
                  printf("The file name '%s' is changed with %s\n", event->name);
                }
              }
          }
      }
      i += EVENT_SIZE + event->len;
  }
    inotify_rm_watch(fd, wd);
  close(fd);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible!

In Unix, file renames are the same as file moves. You're just "moving" a file from one name to a new name in the same directory.

You can use the `IN_MOVE_SELF` event to detect if the file or directory you're watching is moved.

However, I'm not sure if this will detect if the path to the file changes because one of its parent directories is moved or renamed. If you want to check for that, too, you'll have to watch for events on each of the parent directories. Directories receive the events `IN_MOVED_FROM` and `IN_MOVED_TO` when files they contained are moved or renamed. A rename will appear as a `IN_MOVED_FROM` event and then an `IN_MOVED_TO` event with the same `cookie` value so you can correlate them.

Comment: I don't know `inotify` or whatever this is, but am pretty sure this can be more simple done by checking if `fopen(...)` returns `NULL` on a known-to-exist file ? Am I wrong ? I had suggested this just a short while back when OP had asked this question (*this is a duplicate*)

Comment: That will tell you if the file exists right now, but if you want to know if it goes away at some point in the future, you'll have to keep calling `fopen`.

Comment: Alright , Willis, but one *could* just do that, correct ? Further, with the help of `errno` , one could pinpoint why a file would not open too ?

Comment: @AnAnt what does `fopen()` have to do with this? OP is looking specifically for a way to detect renaming through `inotify`.

Comment: *"renames are the same as file moves"* Only on a given mountpoint. `rename(2)` will return `EXDEV` if you try to rename a file to another mountpoint, which requires a copy and delete.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli reading my initial comment would answer this. I am curious if the same can be trivially done with the help of `fopen()` and `errno` checking (being a sucker for portable code). That's all. Also, OP has asked here and in the last question "*is it possible with inotify **or with C?***"

Comment: @AnAnt You could, but you'd only be able to detect if the file was removed (not renamed since you wouldn't know the new name), and the latency between the file being deleted and your program noticing that it had been deleted would be high. You'd have to call `fopen` in a loop, maybe once per second, which means it would be 0.5 seconds on average before you noticed the missing file. Also you can imagine that repeatedly calling `fopen` isn't a scheme that would scale well if you needed to monitor a whole bunch of files.

Comment: @AnAnt OP is asking about `inotify`, you are talking about `fopen`. I don't see why that's a solution to suggest, as it does not accomplish what OP wants. If op asked something similar a while back that doesn't have anything to do with this post.

Comment: @WillisBlackburn this answers my query, thanks. I was assuming the need to detect a rename was not frequent , say like *at launch of program* or such. It doesn't loop/scale well, you're right.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli I request you to read again. OP said "*is it possible with inotify **or with C?***" + I never claimed to solve OP's problem , merely asked a question to someone knowledgable on `inotify`